# Large SQLLite XML database failing

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

my java application takes a users list from a Xml file, and for each user has to some I/O operations.
These operations are:

1. Access to a 5 MB databse using JDBC driver
2. Move some file to a base folder to process them
3. Delete temporary files

It perfectly work when the xml contains only 50 users, but if the number of users in the xml file grows up, the application fails.

While accessing the DB with this code

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:DbName.db");
```

i have

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB$CausedSQLException.fillInStackTrace(NestedDB.java:442)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:250)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.SQLException.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB$CausedSQLException.<init>(NestedDB.java:435)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB._open(NestedDB.java:63)
    at org.sqlite.DB.open(DB.java:77)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.<init>(Conn.java:88)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Now i have 300 users and i solved this by breaking the xml file in 5 parts, but i'd like to understand why this happens.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You're closing all your JDBC connections after using them, right?  I tried looking up NestedDB.java:435, but your version of sqlite doesn't seem to be the most recent.  Maybe you could post or link the relevant source.

Comment: I would have a look at closing or reusing those SQL connections. If you are leaking sql connections, you'll end up getting trouble there.

Answer (score 2):

The solution does sound very scalable. I am impressed it can handle more than few users.

I would not use XML as a database, and I would use only one copy, this way having more user's will not make any difference to resource usage.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of out of memory issue. Try java with -Xmx512m option

Comment: I always launch my application with -Xmx2048m option.
I don't think it is because of memory, but more because of number of system calls. But it's just an idea